# Yii2: duplicate row in database with ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

i develop the product module that add product info into product table, i add the button at the top of my page that copy the current product , i want to duplicate the row of that product ( known by id ) in product table , i user activerecord to duplicate data bud the id always set null and my script cannot duplicate data , my script is :

```
$product_original = Product::findOne($id);
$product_copy = new Product();
$product_copy->attributes = $product_original->attributes
$product_copy->isNewRecord = true;
$product_copy->id = null;
$product_copy->save();
```

after save product $product->save(); always return false, please help me to solve my problem , thank alot :)

Comment: what does `$product_copy->getErrors();` show you ?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to copy attributes and that's it why are you assigning the `$product_copy->isNewrecord` and `$product_copy->id=NULL;`.

The only reason the record is not saved is due to the validation error before saving the record you can check for errors if not saved

Just use

```
$product_original = Product::findOne($id);
$product_copy = new Product();
$product_copy->attributes = $product_original->attributes;
if(!$product_copy->save()){
  //either print errors or redirect
  print_r($product_copy->getErrors());
}
```